# Any better way to write nested if instead of for an if

Tags: python, pandas

I am just starting to learn python so please ignore or let me know if I am not asking this questions properly.

I have a dataframe **df**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [5,6,0,-4], 'B' : [1,2,3,5]})
```

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 0 | 3 |
| -4 | 5 |

I want to do the below:

> IF A greater than 0 then DO;
>
> ----IF B < 2 then NEWVALUE = A * 2
>
> ----ELSE A = A/2
>
> IF A = 0 then CALC_FIELD = NEWVALUE + 2    *# use the **NEWVALUE** column
> that is just created in prior step*

I am using the below combination of 'for' and 'if' to get the output. But is there a better and efficient way to do this ?

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if (df.loc[i, 'A'] > 0) & (df.loc[i, 'B'] < 2): df.loc[i,'NEWVALUE'] =  df.loc[i,'A'] * 2
    if (df.loc[i, 'A'] <= 0): df.loc[i, 'NEWVALUE'] = df.loc[i,'A'] / 2
    if (df.loc[i, 'A'] == 0): df.loc[i, 'CALC_FIELD'] = df.loc[i, 'NEWVALUE'] + 2
```

```
**EXPECTED OUTPUT**
|  A | B  | C  | D  |
| -- | -- | -- |--  |
| 5  | 1  | 10 | Nan|
| 6  | 2  | Nan| Nan| 
| 0  | 3  | 0  | 2  |
| -4 | 5  | -2 |Nan |
```

Comment: is there a typo in your output? isn't the ```nan``` in your C column supposed to be 3? Since A(6) > 0 and B(2) is not less than 2, it should be 6/2 = 3?

Comment: Why does NEWVALUE get populated for last row? `A` is **less than 0** there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a typo in your desired output.

I also wouldn't use a `for` loop for this kind of calculation. I would suggest using `np.select` if you had many conditions and you wanted to create 1 column, but since your aim is to create 2 columns, one simple way would be to use `np.where` twice:

```
import numpy as np
df['C']= np.where((df['A']>0) & (df['B']<2) ,df['A'].mul(2),df['A'].div(2))
df['D']= np.where(df['A'].eq(0),df['C'].add(2),np.nan)
```

Which gets:

```
df
   A  B     C    D
0  5  1  10.0  NaN
1  6  2   3.0  NaN
2  0  3   0.0  2.0
3 -4  5  -2.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a little to add on [the good existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66657910/13386979).  I agree that you should try to avoid the for loop if possible, because the built-in vectorized operations will scale much better.  [See here for the no-nos of iteration over a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/13386979).

An alternative to `np.where` is to just use your same `loc` logic, but with boolean indexing*:

```
df.loc[(df['A'] > 0) & (df['B'] < 2), 'NEWVALUE'] = df['A'] * 2
df.loc[df['A'] <= 0, 'NEWVALUE'] = df['A'] / 2
df.loc[df['A'] == 0, 'CALC_FIELD'] = df['NEWVALUE'] + 2
```

* *I agree with the other comments that you may want to double check that your logic is doing what you purport it to do; it wasn't totally clear in the post.*

In this acute case, this solution is actually slightly slower than the `for` loop, interestingly enough (using `%%timeit`):

- `for` loop: **1.12 ms** ± 69 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
- boolean indexing: **2.41 ms** ± 47.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

However, the real benefit is observed with more data.  If you make your dataset only 10x bigger:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [5,6,0,-4]*10, 'B' : [1,2,3,5]*10})
```

The vectorized indexing is much faster:

- `for` loop: **10.8 ms** ± 83 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
- boolean indexing: **2.37 ms** ± 37.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

The discrepancy grows with the size of the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same code snippet in jupyter notebook, Got the desired output.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [5,6,0,-4], 'B' : [1,2,3,5]})
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if (df.loc[i, 'A'] > 0) & (df.loc[i, 'B'] < 2): df.loc[i,'C'] =  df.loc[i,'A'] * 2
    if (df.loc[i, 'A'] <= 0): df.loc[i, 'C'] = df.loc[i,'A'] / 2
    if (df.loc[i, 'A'] == 0): df.loc[i, 'D'] = df.loc[i, 'C'] + 2
df
```

which gives the expected output:

```
    A   B     C      D
0   5   1   10.0    NaN
1   6   2   NaN     NaN
2   0   3   0.0     2.0
3  -4   5  -2.0     NaN
```